# How to make title bar in android App

Tags: android, title

I`m using jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu and I want to add buttons to title bar like this:

[image: Changed Title Bar]

but I don`t know how make this, please help me

Comment: have you tried searching anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the built-in [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). I Recommend following the tutorials on googles website. Also you should know that the native ActionBar requires API level 11, so if you're interested in a very high compatibility, you need to use a library like [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).